# What is a scenerio in which when a Loader is started and there is already loaded data, which is not yet delivered to the client?

Tags: android, loader, android-loadermanager, android-loader, asynctaskloader

The following pseudocode implementation of `onStartLoading` of a custom Loader implementation is taken from [this blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html).

You can see that according to this method, when a loader enters a started state, i.e. when `onStartLoading` is called, we check if the `mData` is not-null, and if it is not-null, we deliver any previously loaded data immediately. **The question is that what is a use-case in which there is loaded data already which is not yet delivered?**

**Initially I thought, a case might be when the loader enters the started state from the stopped state**, and the observer detected a change in the data content and loaded the data while the loader was in the stopped state. **But that is not true, because** you have mentioned, "Loaders in the stopped state should still monitor the data source for changes *so that the loader will know to force a new load if it is ever started again.*", which implies that loaders keep monitoring the data source for changes but do not load the data in the stopped state, and the new data (after a change is detected) is essentially loaded when the loader enters the started state.

**So what would be the case in which when a loader enters the started state, there is loaded data, stored in `mData`, which is not yet delivered?**

```
@Override
  protected void onStartLoading() {
    if (mData != null) {
      // Deliver any previously loaded data immediately.
      deliverResult(mData);
    }

    // Begin monitoring the underlying data source.
    if (mObserver == null) {
      mObserver = new SampleObserver();
      // TODO: register the observer
    }

    if (takeContentChanged() || mData == null) {
      // When the observer detects a change, it should call onContentChanged()
      // on the Loader, which will cause the next call to takeContentChanged()
      // to return true. If this is ever the case (or if the current data is
      // null), we force a new load.
      forceLoad();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for when the activity is re-created (like during a rotation). The loader has already done its work from before, so it just redelivers it the the (re-created) activity.